# Sails js - How to change the server for a cordova implementation?

Tags: express, sails.js

I'm trying to learn sails + cordova implementation but i didn't find any tutorial

I have a doubt about if i can change the REST server ip

For example, in meteor we have this command

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server my_app_name.meteor.com
```

is there some similar in Sails?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `explicitHost` config parameter.  From the [docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/miscellaneous.html?q=sailsconfigexplicithost):

> By default, Sails will assume localhost as the host that will be listening for incoming requests. This will work in the majority of hosting environments you encounter, but in some cases (OpenShift being one example) you'll need to explicitly declare the host name of your Sails app. Setting explicitHost tells Sails to listen for requests on that host instead of localhost.